# Desaparición de la segunda persona plural en castellano americano

Tags: historia, hispanoamérica, lingüística

¿ A qué se puede deber la desaparición del vosotros/as y las respectivas conjugaciones en el castellano en América ?

La RAE señala en su entrada de "usted" del diccionario virtual que la forma ustedes se usa también en Canarias y parte de Andalucía, pero no hay mayor información.

Sobre esto último, me gustaría también preguntar de paso si hay en castellano algún diccionario y/o gramática que aborde seriamente estas cuestiones y esté disponible online. La máxima obra que conozco, el [diccionario de construcción y régimen de la lengua castellana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diccionario_de_construcci%C3%B3n_y_r%C3%A9gimen_de_la_lengua_castellana), muy por desgraciada no se ha digitalizado para hacerlo más asequible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el XXXI congreso (en 1996) de la AEPE (Asociación europea de profesores de español), en el [documento](https://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/aepe/pdf/congreso_31/congreso_31_08.pdf) de las profesoras Anna Györi y Susana Komlódi, se hace un análisis profundo e interesante sobre el tema, basándose en la evolución lingüística del fenómeno T/V (el contraste entre respeto/confianza en la segunda persona). Se menciona como evoluciona el español desde el siglo de oro en el uso de tú, vos y usted tanto en la península como en el continente.

Lo inicial es ver de donde surge el ustedes y empieza a suplir al vosotros en la península, algo como lo siguiente:

> (...)„La diferencia de uso entre tú/usted vosotros/ustedes se mantiene en la Península (aunque haya variado la frecuencia social de empleo). Pero al mediodía (en Andalucía y en Canarias) los plurales vosotros,-as han sido sustituidos por ustedes." (...)

> (...)En el siglo XVI, al presentarse la mayor confusión acerca de los
> tratamientos tú/vos en la Península, los colonizadores, de bajas capas
> sociales, llegando al Nuevo Mundo difundieron allí ambas formas. Según
> Alcina Franch y Blecua de forma de respeto sirvió el „ tú ". Alarcos Llorach
> afirma que la confusión en torno al uso de „tú" o „vos" en América y la
> total eliminación de „ vosótros/as", ha originado un uso diferente, que sobre
> todo tiene consecuencias en las formas de la conjugación verbal (...)

> (...) A partir del siglo XVIII el tratamiento de respeto se encuentra consolidado en su forma de „ usted/es", con las terceras personas de singular y de plural, mientras el tratamiento de „tú" y de „vosotros" corresponderá a los tratamientos de solidaridad, familiaridad, confianza mutua y para expresar relaciones de poder, no-reciprocidad. (...)

Ya con una base histórica de qué pasó en España, vamos con tu pregunta. El español que llega a América sienta firmes bases en los siglos XVI y XVII (entre 1550 y 1700 aprox.)

> (...) en el siglo XVII se generaliza el usted.  Las cortes virreinales adoptaron y difundieron estos cambios en las formas de trato social (...)

El respeto impuesto con el usted/es se hace popular en el continente, sin haber llegado a fortalecerse el vosotros como fórmula de confianza. Cabe decir que a América llegan el hablar culto y el vulgar. En particular, si revisas en el CORDE (el Corpus Diacrónico del Español) el uso del pronombre *vosotros* supera al de *ustedes* en América desde 1600 hasta 1850, unas 3 décadas tras la independencia, donde se empieza a notar como se fortalece y se consolida el ustedes, dando a entender que el primero era usado como forma cordial entre peninsulares o entre los criollos (esto puede verse en cartas de Bolivar, de Hidalgo, de O'Higgins por citar a algunos próceres) cuya presencia disminuye tras la independencia, y el segundo del pueblo al superior, o entre miembros del pueblo.

Answer (score 0):

según tengo entendido, el uso de "usted" en España es de uso formal. En Andalucía, por ejemplo (aunque creo que es en toda España), usamos "usted/ustedes" para hablar a personas que no conocemos y referirnos a ellas formalmente o en documentos oficiales o formales.

Por otra parte, al hablar con las personas de habla hispana en América siempre me han dicho que el "vosotros/as" es demasiado formal para ellos/as, algo que para mí suena de lo más normal.
Entonces en respuesta a tu pregunta y en base a mi experiencia, no hay ninguna desaparición del "vosotros/as", solo que el uso del usted/es es mucho más popular en América en comparación con España.

Sobre la parte de las conjugaciones, cabe decir que "usted" se conjuga igual que "él/ella" mientras que "ustedes" como "ellos/as", aunque dependiendo de la región y de la situación este último puede conjugarse también como "vosotros/as".

En la RAE, puedes ver también las conjugaciones de todos los verbos (por ejemplo, del verbo "hacer": https://dle.rae.es/hacer#conjugacionfIOsOqS)